# Wiring a bean from dependency module

Tags: spring, spring-3

I have created a configuration project which essentially creates couple of beans with configuration stereotype. Then, I want this project to be reused across by my clients. 
I have added this config project as a maven dependency, but my client project is not having those beans i have created as part of configuration project. 
Could someone help

Comment: just place @ComponentScan("you.configurations.base.package")

Comment: Ok! thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried it?)

Comment: Nope. I Will try it now..

Comment: It worked. But already my application has @SpringBootApplication annotated. Why it's not finding my bean with it

Comment: Any other way to fix this?

Comment: `SpringBootApplication` under the hood contains `ComponentScan` without specifying a base package. That means that it says to Spring to scan the package where a class annotated with `SpringBootApplication` resides and all the packages recusrively. And that's it. If you place you `Configuration` somewhere there - it will create it during startup, otherwise not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer is the following: you should place

```
@ComponentScan("you.configurations.base.package")
```

on one of your configuration (in the current application, one that `@SpringBootApplication` sees) or on the class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

The explanation is as follows: `@SpringBootApplication` under the hood contains `@ComponentScan` without specifying a base package. That means that it says to Spring to scan the package where the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` resides and all the packages recursively. And that's it. If you place you `@Configuration` somewhere there - it will create it during startup, otherwise not.

Comment: Eventhough i added @SpringBootApplication in my configuration project, the client using it didn't find the bean

Comment: @Ziaur Nooo, you should place `@ComponentScan("you.configurations.base.package")` on it

Comment: That works fine. But as per your answer above "or a class with @SpringBootApplicationannotation." It should work right? It is not working even though I add spring boot application

Comment: @Ziaur I meant place ON SpringBootApplication, not SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this by enabling spring-boot autoconfiguration

Create classpath->resources->META-INF->spring.factories file
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=[add your class with you need to be loaded during application load time]